# Facebook Business Extension Setup

Tags: facebook

I followed the instructions here https://www.facebook.com/business/help/532749253576163 to install FB Business Extension to my local Magento 2.3 dev instance as well as Staging environment. Installation went fine, but I'm having two problems:

1. When I try to set up the Facebook Business Extension, the connection appears to succeed. However, when the dialog box closes, the Setup page still shows "Connection Pending." When I go back to Admin panel --> Stores --> Facebook --> Setup, I receive a prompt to connect again.
2. When I go to Admin panel --> Stores --> Settings --> Configuration --> Facebook --> Business Extension, the page returns as blank with a 500 error.

Does anyone have the FB Business Extension setup and working? I'm trying to implement this extension to leverage its CAPI abilities.

Answer (score 0):

Same issues and same configuration apparently (2.3), looking forward to solve this.
Since the issue is 3mo, any luck o did you gave up?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/195794)